# 'cannot attach kprobe, probe entry may not exist' when execute trace-bpfcc

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, ebpf

I am following [bcc Tutorial](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md) and trying to execute the `trace-bpfcc` command: `sudo trace-bpfcc 'sys_execve "%s", arg1'`

The command fails with an error:
`cannot attach kprobe, probe entry may not exist Failed to attach BPF program b'probe_sys_execve_1' to kprobe b'sys_execve'`

While searching the web, I found that such an error can occur if the symbol `__x64_sys_execve` is missing in `/proc/kallsyms`, but I have one there.

I don't have any kernel development experience at all, what do I need to do to fix this issue?

My distro is Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the correct symbol yourself: **`__x64_sys_execve`**, you want to use the same when running the command:

```
$ sudo trace-bpfcc '__x64_sys_execve "%s", arg1'
```

There is no function called simply `__sys_execve` in your kernel and you have to match the exact symbol for BCC to find the relevant function.